# ComputeEnvironment went INVALID with error: The security group 'XXXX' does not exist

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-batch

Below my CloudFormation template.

I have added all the resource code. (Please excuse the indentation issue - copy paste. I assure readers the template is running).

```
  ---
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Description: Sets up your AWS Batch Environment for running  workflows

Metadata:
  AWS::CloudFormation::Interface:
    ParameterGroups:
      - Label:
          default: Compute Environment Config
        Parameters:
          - ComputeEnvironmentName
          - VpcId
          - SubnetIds
          - MinvCpus
          - MaxvCpus
          - DesiredvCpus
      - Label:
          default: Job Definition
        Parameters:
          - JobDefinitionName
          - DockerImage
          - Vcpus
          - Memory
          - Command
          - RetryNumber
      - Label:
          default: Job Queue
        Parameters:
          - JobQueueName


Parameters:
  VpcId:
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::VPC::Id'
    Description: >-
      VpcId of where the whole batch should be deployed. The VPC should have
      2 private subnets.
  SubnetIds:
    Type: List<AWS::EC2::Subnet::Id>
    Description: Subnets you want your batch compute environment to launch in. Recommend private subnets
  MinvCpus:
    Type: String
    Description: Minimum number of CPUs in the compute environment. Default 0.
    Default: 0
    AllowedPattern: "[0-9]+"
  DesiredvCpus:
    Type: String
    Description: Desired number of CPUs in the compute environment to launch with. Default 0.
    Default: 0
    AllowedPattern: "[0-9]+"
  MaxvCpus:
    Type: String
    Description: Maximum number of CPUs in the compute environment. Should be >= than MinCpus
    Default: 256
    AllowedPattern: "[0-9]+"
  RetryNumber:
    Type: String
    Default: "1"
    Description: Number of retries for each AWS Batch job. Integer required.
    MaxLength: 1
    AllowedPattern: "[1-9]"
    ConstraintDescription: Value between 1 and 9

  DockerImage:
    Type: String
    Description: Docker image used to run your jobs
  Vcpus:
    Type: Number
    Description: vCPUs available to Jobs. Default is usually fine
    Default: 2
  Memory:
    Type: Number
    Description: Memory (in MB) available to Jobs. Default is usually fine
    Default: 2000
  JobQueueName:
    Type: String
    Description: Enter job queue Name
  JobDefinitionName:
    Type: String
    Description: Enter JobDefinition Name for the batch
  ComputeEnvironmentName:
    Type: String
    Description: Enter name of the Compute Environment
  VPCCidr:
    Type: String
    Description: 'Cidr Block of the VPC, allows for ssh access internally.'
    Default: '10.0.0.0/8'
    MinLength: "9"
    MaxLength: "18"
    AllowedPattern: "(\\d{1,3})\\.(\\d{1,3})\\.(\\d{1,3})\\.(\\d{1,3})/(\\d{1,2})"
    ConstraintDescription: "Must be valid CIDR notation (i.e. x.x.x.x/x)."
  Command:
    Type: CommaDelimitedList
    Description: The command that is passed to the container
  CreateNewRepository:
    Default: false
    Description: >-
      Set this to true if you want to create a new Repository, else
      it will not create a new one
    Type: String
    AllowedValues:
      - true
      - false   
  RepositoryName:
    Type: String
    Description: Enter name of the new Repository.

Conditions:
  CreateRepository: !Equals
    - !Ref CreateNewRepository
    - true
  isCommandPresent: !Not [!Equals [!Ref CreateNewRepository, '']]

Resources:
  JobDefinition:
    Type: AWS::Batch::JobDefinition
    Properties:
      Type: container
      JobDefinitionName: !Ref JobDefinitionName
      ContainerProperties:
        Image: !Ref DockerImage
        Vcpus: !Ref Vcpus
        Memory: !Ref Memory
        Command: !Ref Command
        ReadonlyRootFilesystem: true
        Privileged: true
      RetryStrategy:
        Attempts: !Ref RetryNumber
  JobQueue:
   Type: AWS::Batch::JobQueue
   Properties:
    ComputeEnvironmentOrder:
      - Order: 1
        ComputeEnvironment: !Ref MyComputeEnv
    State: ENABLED
    Priority: 10
    JobQueueName: !Ref JobQueueName

  myVPCSecurityGroup:
    Type: "AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup"
    Properties: 
      GroupDescription: Security group for batch process.
      SecurityGroupEgress:
        - CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0
          IpProtocol: '-1'
      SecurityGroupIngress:
        - CidrIp: !Ref VPCCidr
          IpProtocol: tcp
          FromPort: '22'
          ToPort: '22'
      VpcId: !Ref VpcId
  MyComputeEnv:
   Type: AWS::Batch::ComputeEnvironment
   Properties:
    Type: MANAGED
    ServiceRole: !GetAtt awsBatchServiceRole.Arn
    ComputeEnvironmentName: !Ref ComputeEnvironmentName
    ComputeResources:
      MinvCpus: !Ref MinvCpus
      MaxvCpus: !Ref MaxvCpus
      DesiredvCpus: !Ref DesiredvCpus
      SecurityGroupIds: [!GetAtt myVPCSecurityGroup.GroupId]
      Type: EC2
      Subnets: !Ref SubnetIds
      InstanceRole: !GetAtt InstanceProfile.Arn
      InstanceTypes:
        - optimal
    State: ENABLED
  awsBatchServiceRole:
      Type: AWS::IAM::Role
      Properties:
        AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
          Version: 2012-10-17
          Statement:
            - Effect: Allow
              Principal:
                Service:
                  - "batch.amazonaws.com"
              Action:
                - "sts:AssumeRole"
        ManagedPolicyArns:
        - arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AWSBatchServiceRole
  ecsInstanceRole:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      RoleName: InstanceRole
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: 2012-10-17
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              Service:
                - "ec2.amazonaws.com"
            Action:
              - "sts:AssumeRole"
      ManagedPolicyArns:
      - "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonEC2FullAccess"
      - "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AmazonEC2ContainerServiceforEC2Role"
  InstanceProfile:
    Type: AWS::IAM::InstanceProfile
    Properties:
      InstanceProfileName: InstanceProfile
      Roles:
      - !Ref ecsInstanceRole
  MyRepository: 
    Type: AWS::ECR::Repository
    Condition: CreateRepository
    Properties: 
      RepositoryName: !Ref RepositoryName
      RepositoryPolicyText: 
        Version: "2012-10-17"
        Statement: 
          - 
            Sid: AllowPushPull
            Effect: Allow
            Principal: "*"
            Action: 
              - "ecr:*"
```

I am getting this error:

> Operation failed, ComputeEnvironment went INVALID with error: CLIENT_ERROR - The security group 'sg-d9b85d91' does not exist

I don't know what is wrong with the code but strangely, the SecurityGroupIds created by myVPCSecurityGroup is sg-2869f263 but ComputeEnvironment is trying to find sg-d9b85d91.

Comment: Agreed the error doesn't make sense. Check if you have another resource called myVPCSecurityGroup. CFN may not warn of duplicates.
Please post your full template that can be used to reproduce this.

Comment: Thanks for help Jeshan. I can assure there is no other resource.

Comment: ok paste a full reproducible yaml please. I'd like to take a look

Comment: Ok. Added the full yaml.

Comment: Vikas, the template you provided "works on my machine". I suspect that you may have chosen a subnet that isn't in the vpc that you chose. I'm quite sure it's vpc-related

Comment: Yes. Even I am able to create when I use default vpc. But my main concern is the secruitygroupid which I am creating is sg-xxxxxx but compute environment is trying to finding  sg-d9b85d91. Why is that??

Comment: I just think that it's an error that's hiding another one

Comment: Have you found the solution yet @VikasRathore?

Comment: @zoonoo: No, I setup a new vpc and subnet. Now its working fine. and it don't matter but I took myVPCSecurityGroup code out and placed below MyComputeEnv.

Answer (score 0):

taking a stab in the dark here just working for my mobile phone but I think it's because you don't have a V PC to your computer environment possibly

Comment: I have the VPC. It is showing in the drop-down. actually, we have 3. one default and 2 custom.

Comment: Are you sure you're picking a security group that's in the VPC and not in a different VPC?

Comment: I am sure TIM. I have created 4 subnets. 2 public and 2 private. I am choosing private subnets

Answer (score 0):

Disabling the Compute Environment in the UI and enabling it back again fixed the issue.